# how to use a variable in a section into SQL from delphi

Tags: mysql, sql, delphi, delphi-xe, rad

```
source:= tabledemap.FieldByName('table source').AsString + '('+ tabledemap.FieldByName('colonne source').AsString+')';
  showmessage(source)  ;
```

The source value is the column: a.name (firsatname)
I want to insert in this column the string 't'
But the problem I want to use the value of the source variable in a sql request like this

```
 FDQuery6.SQL.Add ('INSERT INTO  source  Values ( "t" ) ');

     FDQuery6.Execute;

      showmessage('row inserted');
```

But the program fails to use the text of the value of the source variable and think that source is a name of a table and displays to  me

```
---------------------------
Notification des exceptions du débogueur
---------------------------
Le projet x a déclenché la classe d'exception EMySQLNativeException avec le message '[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] Table 'a.source' doesn't exist'.
```

I have tried "source" , +source+  but it won't work also .
If anyone can help me to use the text of the source variable in the SQL query I will be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

In FireDAC you can paremetrize table and field names by using preprocessor macros. For example:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO &TableName (&FieldName) VALUES "ConstValue"';
FDQuery.MacroByName('TableName').AsIdentifier := 'MyTable';
FDQuery.MacroByName('FieldName').AsIdentifier := 'MyField';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
```

For details about this kind of macros, see the [**substitution variables**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Substitution_Variables) topic.